# Php if condition inside foreach

Tags: php, if-statement

I have following arrays.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cash
            [1] => 91.16
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>Credit
            [1] => 61.48
        )
)
```

I want to do something like this .

```
foreach ($value as $values) {
// Where $values is the above array . I want to traverse array dynamically and put if condition .
if($values[0][0] != "Cash")
echo "Cash";
}
```

The above code does not working . Please help me on this . How can I place if condition dynamically inside foreach loop.

Comment: Just remove the last `[0]`: `$values[0]`

Comment: Just simply use if($values[0] != "Cash") there is no multidimensional array anymore

Comment: You should debug your code with something like var_dump when you have this type of problems...

Comment: do a simple search on how foreach works..

Comment: I dont want to check it for Cash only , want to check it for all like Cash , Credit . So that first [0] index will be iterate dynamically .

Comment: @user2656780 i have updated my answer,plz check once is it working as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
  if (!in_array($value[0], array('Cash', 'Credit'))) {
    echo 'Neither cash nor credit';
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
    foreach ($array as $values) {
          if($values[0] != "cash" && $values[0] == "credit"){
           echo "It is a credit ";
          }
   else if($values[1] != "credit" && $values[0] == "cash"){
      echo "it is a cash"."<br>";
      }
```

Comment: I tried this , but its printing Cash one time , which it should not .

Comment: so what you want?you want to print?

Comment: If Cash , Credit are there in array , then it should not print Cash or Credit depending on if condition .

Comment: No.Don't want to print on that case.

Comment: @user2656780 Its printing cash one time since cash is only present one time in the array.  Do u want to check wether cash or credit is present in the array?? What is it that you actually need???